# Excluding lines conditional upon multiple fields with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a pretty simple `awk` question:

I have the following file `test1.txt`

```
ids op  count
id1 op1 1
id7 op1 2
id13    op1 3
id4 op1 4
id10    op1 5
id11    op2 1
id2 op2 2
id8 op2 3
id14    op2 4
id5 op2 5
```

I would like to **exclude** certain rows based on the `op` and `count` columns. For example **exclude** anything in `op2` that has a `count` from 2 to 5, finally giving me the following `test2.txt`:

```
ids op  count
id1 op1 1
id7 op1 2
id13    op1 3
id4 op1 4
id10    op1 5
id11    op2 1
id5 op2 5
```

I'm looking for an `awk` code that would do something like:

```
awk '{
    if($2 ~ /op2/ && $3>1 && $3<5)
    skip
    else
    print $0
    }' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

This code actually works. But I appreciate any suggestions for 1 liners.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hmm the code above seems to be working for this example actually...

Comment: move the condition out of the if block and negate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
awk 'NR==1 || !($2=="op2" && $3<5 && $3>1)' test.file
```

Note that an awk program basically has the following form:

```
CONDITION { ACTIONS }
```

where the default action is `print`. That means if condition expands to `true` and you specify no action, awk will print the input line.

The logic means:

*print all lines which **don't** match **both** of the following conditions*:

- *op==op2*
- *2 < count >= 5*

Comment: well this code is giving me only 1 line: `id5 op2 5`  and not the range. Also I want to **exclude** the things that satisfy the condition not extract them.

Comment: yeah, actually my code works too -- lol... but I appreciate your answer. your conditional is not correct though, `$2=="op2" && $3<5 && $3>1` gives what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` one-liner

```
$ awk '$2!="op2" || 2>$3 || $3>4' file

ids op  count
id1 op1 1
id7 op1 2
id13    op1 3
id4 op1 4
id10    op1 5
id11    op2 1
id5 op2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If yo want an onliner, try:

```
awk '($2 != "op2") || ($3 <= 1) || ($3 >= 5) { print }' test1.txt > test2.txt
```